# Are there any risks running ADD COLUMN AFTER in MariaDB/InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I am a DBA using MariaDB 10.4.13 on Centos7 and Centos8.

Our development team need a new column in the middle of an existing (small) table.

So we used this one:

`ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN c1 enum('DEL', 'END') not null default 'END' AFTER c5;`

This works fine, but I am new in this topic. (I used to work as a DBA for MS-SQL and DB2).

I do not know what MariaDB exactly (physical) does using ADD AFTER. Are there any risks? Could this cause any problems? In DB2 this is not that easy.

Comment: What sort of risks are you worried about - the table being locked during the running of the statement? You could clone your live database and run the command on the clone, to see if there are any issues.

Comment: The DDL operations will block DML operations including read and write.So when your table has lots of data, threre will be a long time block.For a better choice, you can use online ddl operations which will not block DML operations.

Comment: "Small" table -- just do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you add a new column as the last column of a table or in the middle makes no difference. Any alteration that changes the size of a row creates a new tablespace and copies the data to a new tablespace. This does not cause problems.

It does lock the table while the copy is in progress. But you said it's a small table. That's not very specific (I don't know what you consider small or large), but it's likely it won't take very long. Perhaps a second or two.

But if the table is in constant use by an application, even a brief lock could cause the application to experience an outage. You should talk to your manager about arranging the best time to do the alter that will not impact the application using that table.